# Trouble getting past initial splash pages in Benzinga using Selenium to scrape webpages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to scrape the analyst pages in Benzinga, but I'm having trouble getting past the initial multiple advert/splash pages. My code seems to work for the first two just by using sleep functions to let the webpage load and settle, but the third one (wants you to subscribe) seems  to be some sort of "mouse over" or mouse click because it seems to load only after one clicks on the http page. Also I was wondering if some of the buttons have unique codes embedded in them so on one computer it works, but on another computer the selenium click might fail. In the code below this is the 0pVDSU9IuxoaeJZCJ7Qz.

The code so far is:

```
import time
import copy
from lxml import html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

def get_benzinga_data():
    ffox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    #ffox_options.set_headless()
    tol_amount = 5
    tols_curr = 0
    bp = False
    ff = webdriver.Firefox(options = ffox_options)
    ff.get('https://benzinga.com/analyst-stock-ratings')
    time.sleep(40)    
    # wait for the large circle advertisment
    ff.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="prosper-ButtonElement--0pVDSU9IuxoaeJZCJ7Qz"]').click()
    time.sleep(30)
    # wait for the 2nd advertisment
    ff.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]').click()
    time.sleep(20)
    # click to try to get mouse over/click on text to force next popup
    ff.find_element("xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p').click()

    time.sleep(20)
    # fails here as selenium can't find the next popup since it may have not been generated
    ff.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/button').click()


get_benzinga_data()
```

gives error message:
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/button

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the third popup is activated when you click on the webpage. So the trick is not to click the Benzinga webpage with your mouse. Leave the first two get element statements and delete the third. You may need to adjust the sleep depending upon how fast the pages load.

Another solution is to create an account and log in. Then you only get one advertisement popup that you can remove with selenium code. The other popups do not appear.